# $A = B^2$ nilpotent

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be different $3 \times 3$ matrices. $A$ is nilpotent.
What kind of Jordan canonical form does $A$ need to have, to guarantee, that $A = B^2$?

Can I assume that there is more than only one JCF?

Comment: To clarify: you want to know which nilpotent $A\in\Bbb C^{3\times3}$ are such that there is some matrix $B\ne A$ satisfying $A=B^2$, do you not?

Comment: Since $B$ is also nilpotent, $B^3=0$ and hence $A^2=B^4=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A^k=0$ for some $k>0$ then $B^{2k}=A^{k}=0$, and hence $B$ is also nilpotent. This means that the minimal polynomial for $B$ is a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $\leq 3$ which is a divisor of $x^{2k}.$ This means that $q(x)=x^3$ is also divisible by the minimal polynomial for $B,$ and hence $B^3=0.$ Then $A^2=B^4=0.$

So, $A^2=0.$ This means the minimal polynomial for $A$ must be either $x$ or $x^2.$

This gives us either $A=0$ or the Jordan normal form:

$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Is it possible to get this form? Yes, if $$B'=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ then $B'^2=A'.$ So if $A=MA'M^{-1}$ then $B=MB'M^{-1}$ satisfies $A=B^2.$

So $A$ is a square nilpotent if and only if either $A=0$ or the Jordan normal form of $A$ is $A'.$

Answer (score 0):

If $A = B^2$ then $B$ is also nilpotent.  By noting that the square of a Jordan block of size $m$ for eigenvalue $0$ has Jordan form consisting of two blocks of size $m/2$ (if $m$ is even) or blocks of size $(m-1)/2$ and $(m+1)/2$ (if $m>1$ is odd), we see that we must be able to match up the Jordan blocks of $A$  so that each block of size $> 1$ is matched to a block of the same size or one differing by $1$; blocks of size $1$ can be either unmatched or matched to a block of size $2$.  So for the $3 \times 3$ case the possibilities for Jordan canonical form of $A$ are
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}\ \text{and}\ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0}$$
(three blocks of size $1$, or one of size $2$ and one of size $1$).